# "Webpage has expired" $_SESSIONS in PHP

Tags: php, session

In my web-application I'm using `$_SESSIONS` but sometimes, when the users hits the backspace key he gets:

> Webpage has expired

message.

Why is this happening? What can i do to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also has to do with the cache control directives sent to the browser.
Take a look at http://de.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter and http://shiflett.org/articles/how-to-avoid-page-has-expired-warnings to learn more about the cache settings.

http://shiflett.org/articles/how-to-avoid-page-has-expired-warnings:

> Recap

To avoid "Page Has Expired" warnings, set session.cache_limiter to private, and make sure that any form using the POST method submits to an intermediate processing page that redirects the user to a different URL.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't have anything to do with `$_SESSION` variables, it has to do with you transferring information between pages using POST method. If you want to avoid it you need to use GET method instead of POST.

Comment: Also, it's only something IE displays as far as I know.

Comment: Firefox displays a dialog informing you that you need to re-send information to view this page (or something along those lines) with options to Re-sent or Cancel.

Comment: You shouldn't blindly replace a POST request by a GET request.
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.1.1 :
"In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
other than retrieval."

Comment: As a side note, to avoid this, once you finish your POST processing, redirect to another page.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't blindly do it, but he hasn't supplied any detail about what functionality is actually causing this. We can't really assume that replacing it with GET is either a good or bad idea. If it's something that the user is regularly trying to go "Back" to, my guess is that it's something like search results. That's why I went ahead and suggested a replacement with GET. We really can't know unless he tells us though.

Answer (score 2):

Like Chad said, that's the result of going back to a page that was the result of a POST request. And like the comments said, you can't just replace a POST with a GET, because that's a bad idea for a variety of reasons.

However, you can combine the two: let the request be a POST, but issue a Location header redirect, which the browser will then execute as a GET. To the user this will look like a single operation, but to the browser it will be a POST followed by a GET, which effectively eliminates this issue.