# PHP document expired on form post

Tags: php, html, post

I have page 1 with form (POST) that posts to page 2 that if form POSTed shows result if form is not POSTed and page 2 open it shows other content based on PHP `if`.
Page 2 has link to page 3 and when i post form from page 1 -> page 2 and go to page 3 via link then i click back and get "Document expired"

Someone told me its n normal, however why's that happening? I assumed if PHP check's POST variable not exists and gives different content to page it should how fine.

Is there any way's to make it work or its coded into browser to behave like that?

Edit Answer: `<?php session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire'); ... ?>` fixed it

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Webpage has expired" $_SESSIONS in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794465/webpage-has-expired-sessions-in-php)

Comment: I believe it is a browser issue. When you go back (with the browser back button) to a page that was POSTed to, the browser will either ask you if you want to send the data again or give you an expired page. Which of these happen will depend on the browser you are using. Unfortunately there is no way around it because this all happens before the request is sent to the server, so changing the PHP code will have no effect

Comment: It always ask if to post again or not, but this time it did not it just shows expired page right away

Comment: `<?php session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire'); ... ?>` fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form processing script (Page 2, I think) you should redirect once you've processed the data. That way the user never sees that error.

Example:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // save something to database
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/page2');
    exit;
}

// other content
```

Comment: `<?php session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire'); ... ?>` fixed it